# Pointing a domain name to a VPS

Tags: ip, vps, nameserver, domain-name

I just got a VPS. All the host gave me was an IP address to have the domain point to.

Lets say my domain is mydomain.com

So what I did was I removed the nameserver (not the NS records, but the actual nameserver) values. Then I added 3 A records to point to the VPS IP for the following:

ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com
mydomain.com

The host kept telling me I had to set up ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com. So I did.

Then I created 2 NS records for mydomain.com with the values of ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com

Now after I did all that, I tried setting the nameservers to ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com but it wouldn't let me do it.

Is what I've done enough to get my domain to point to the VPS properly? Should I just wait for propogation now?

This is the first time I've tried this so I'm a little lost.

Comment: Go to the blackboard and write 100 times "DNS does **not** propogate".

Comment: "it wouldn't let me do it" is not a very good problem description, especially where we can't tell what the first "it" refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your domain DNS control panel (provided by your registrar) and use it to reset your DNS to it's default configuration.

Once you've done that create an A record (or modify the existing one) for mydomain.com and enter the IP address for your VPS in the appropriate field.

Don't play with the NS records.

Comment: ive done that, but what do i set the nameservers to? when i try to set ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com the registrar simple will not accept those as nameservers.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to change the NS entries ?

Comment: ok im stupid as all hell. my registrar had nameservers i had to set the domain to in order for it to manage the DNS. i just found them now and set the domain to those nameservers, and i kept the A record to point to the VPS IP. i think its going to work now.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is create an A record at your domain hoster's DNS for mydomain.com to point your server's IP address. Do not replace the name servers, or they will point to nowhere.

This is for the most simple scenario that

- you do not host your own DNS, but use your domain hoster's DNS (e.g. Godaddy)
- you don't need reverse lookup, MX, or other records

In many other scenarios, like for the primary domain on a shared hosting account, or subdomains that you added there, the web hoster creates the DNS records on their DNS server. That's when you replace the name server addresses at your domain hoster with the DNS servers of your web hoster. But a VPS account does not automatically come with DNS

If you ran your own DNS on your VPS server, you would replace the name server addresses for the domain with your server IPs. But you did not mention any of this, so I assume you pointed the name servers to your VPS, but there is no DNS running on the box. Thus, nothing resolves.